# skip the first error of a matplotlib errorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, errorbar

When trying to plot an [errorbar](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar.html) using matplotlib and skipping the first error I ran into some difficulties. What I want is to plot an errorbar but to skip the first value for the plot.

So I tried to adapt a matplotlib [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_limits_simple.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-errorbar-limits-simple-py) as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
x = np.arange(10)
y = 2.5 * np.sin(x / 20 * np.pi)
yerr = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)

plt.errorbar(x, y + 3, yerr=yerr, label='both limits (default)')
    
lim = [False]+[True]*9
plt.errorbar(x, y + 1, yerr=yerr, uplims=lim, lolims=lim,
             label='only last 9 values with error visualized')

plt.legend(loc='lower right')
```

So I tried to use `uplims` and `lowlims` and get rid of the arrow tips later. What's happening when I set the upper and lower limit to `False` is that a normal error is plotted instead of none.
The desired output and my approach is shown in the following figure:
[image]

I'm aware of the `errorevery` parameter of the errorbar, but as I only want to skip the first error I think it's not applicable to my problem.

Some kind of workaround could be to first plot a normal line with the values, then get rid of the first entry and plot an errorbar for the remaining values. I'm asking if there's a better solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just make the first error value `0`, if I understand correctly.

```
yerr = np.linspace(0.05, 0.2, 10)
...
yerr[0] = 0
plt.errorbar(x, y + 1, yerr=yerr, 
             label='only last 9 values with error visualized')
```

[image]

Comment: You pointed me into the right direction, I ended up using `yerr[0]=float('NaN')`.